# Computer Networking - Basic Circuit Switching - Calculate Max Number of Connections

Tags: computer-networks

I don't understand how to solve this problem. I understand the concept of bottleneck links but I can't seem to solve this specific question type.

For Question 3, I know the answer is 31 and that is achieved by adding the connections from A - B and the connections from C - D. I have absolutely no idea why that is needed to obtain the answer and I would be incredibly grateful if someone could provide some insight.

I have a feeling I'm just not understanding what the question is asking

For Question 4, I don't understand why the answer is no.

[image: Question 3 - The first question I am stuck on]

[image: Question 4]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGqJ3.png)